# No renombrar arreglo del localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular

Estimados tengo este método que añade un arreglo de una lista  y se va añadiendo la lista y en el loclastorage, todo bien solo que cuando se sale de la lista y se quiere seguir añadiendo elementos de la lista los items del localstorage se sobrescriben o borran necesito que se sumen a los que ya existen, espero me puedan ayudar.

el localstorage guarda así mi arreglo pero cuando ejecuto el método agregar(); me borra esos arreglos y me reemplaza por los nuevos, cuando abro de nuevo el modal, quisiera que no los borré si no que se sume a  la lista que ya se tiene, espero se entienda. leí un poco del método ...rest, para conservar los items anteriores, he probado pero no me resulta me sigue eliminando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";

import { CouponService } from "../../../../business/savings-wallet/services/couponService";
import {
  CouponUSer,
  CouponUSerDet,
} from "../../../../business/savings-wallet/models/registration-user.model";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import * as moment from "moment";
import { IDiscountCodeRequestParams } from '../../../../shared/models/discount-code/discount-code.model';
import { IDiscountCode } from '../../../../shared/models/shopping-cart/shopping-cart-request.interface';
import { isArray } from '../../../../shared/helpers/objects-equal';
import { CheckoutDiscountCodeFormService } from '../../../../business/checkout/checkout-forms/checkout-discount-code-form.service';
import { DiscountCodeImplementService } from '../../../../business/checkout/checkout-services/discount-code-implement.service';
import { catchError, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ShoppingCartRequestService } from '../../../../shared/service/shopping-cart/shopping-cart-request.service';
import { CouponsStoreService } from '../../../../business/checkout/checkout-stores/coupons-store.service';
import { ErrorScheduleModalService } from '../../../../business/checkout/checkout-services/error-schedule-modal.service';
import { ShoppingCartImplementService } from '../../../../shared/service/shopping-cart/shopping-cart-implement.service';
import { CheckoutPurchaseSummaryStoreService } from '../../../../business/checkout/checkout-stores/checkout-purchase-summary-store.service';
import { ShoppingCartResponse } from '../../../../shared/models/shopping-cart/shopping-cart-response.model';
import { ProductShoppingCart } from '../../product-card/models/product-shopping-cart/product-shopping-cart.model';
import { TaggingService } from '../../../../atm-services/tagging.service';
import { Coupon } from '../../../../business/savings-wallet/models/coupon.model';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { error } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

moment.locale("es");

interface IDiscountCodeTag {
  code: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: "fp-modal-coupons",
  templateUrl: "./modal-coupons.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./modal-coupons.component.scss"],
})
export class ModalCouponsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() coupons: Coupon[] = [];
  @Input() addCoupons: Coupon[] = [];
  public discountCodeTags: IDiscountCodeTag[] = [];
  coupon: Coupon;
  public discountsList?: IDiscountCode[];
  public couponInput: Coupon;
  token: string = "";
  public isValidatingCupon = false;
  private isShootTag = false;
  public listado: boolean = true;
  public detalle: boolean = false;

  public responseCard = {};
  loading = true;
  isinvalid = true;


  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalCouponsComponent>,
    private couponService: CouponService,
    public discountCodeForm: CheckoutDiscountCodeFormService,
    private discountCodeImplement: DiscountCodeImplementService,
    private shoppingCartRequest: ShoppingCartRequestService,
    private couponsStore: CouponsStoreService,
    private errorScheduleModalService: ErrorScheduleModalService,
    private shoppingCartImplement: ShoppingCartImplementService,
    private purchaseSummaryStore: CheckoutPurchaseSummaryStoreService,
    private fb: FormBuilder

  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCoupons();

  }



  closeDialog() {
    this.leerLocalStorage();
  }
 

  leerLocalStorage() {
      if (!localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr')) {
        return;
    }

  const addCoupons: Coupon[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr'));

  const cartRequest = this.shoppingCartRequest.shoppingCartRequest;
  const discountArray = isArray(cartRequest.discountsList) ? cartRequest.discountsList : [];

  addCoupons.forEach(coupon => {
    const discount = {
      couponCode: coupon.barCode,
      couponId: null,
      discountByReferenceId: null,
      } as IDiscountCode;
      discountArray.push(discount);
  });

    cartRequest.discountsList = discountArray;
    this.shoppingCartRequest.updateShoppingCartRequest = cartRequest;
    this.loadProductSummary();
    this.couponsStore.addCoupon(this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value as string);
  }



  loadCoupons() {
    this.couponService
      .getApiKey(firebase.auth().app.options)
      .subscribe((key) => {
        const request = new CouponUSer({
          identificationDocument: sessionStorage.getItem("document"),
          limitAvailableStatus: 40,
          companyCode: "MF",
        });
        this.couponService
          .getCoupons(request, key.access_token)
          .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response.data, 'Cupones')
            if (response.error !== null) {
            } else {
              this.coupons = response.data.filter(
                coupons => coupons.couponStatus !== 2 && coupons.omnicanal !== 'N'
              )
              this.loading = false;
              
            }
          });
      });
  }

  

  openDialogDetail(coupon: Coupon) {
    this.couponService
      .getApiKey(firebase.auth().app.options)
      .subscribe((key) => {
        const requestDet = new CouponUSerDet({
          identificationDocument: sessionStorage.getItem("document"),
          id: coupon.barCode,
          couponTypeCode: 1,
          parentCampaignCode: "",
          idTracking: null,
          companyCode: "MF",
        });
        this.couponService
          .getCouponById(requestDet, key.access_token)
          .subscribe((response) => {
            this.coupon = response.data as Coupon;
            
          });
      });
    return (this.listado = false), (this.detalle = true);
  }

  

  back() {
    return (this.listado = true), (this.detalle = false);
  }

  agregar(coupon: Coupon) {
    if (this.addCoupons.some((p) => p === coupon)) return;
    this.addCoupons.push(coupon);
    this.guardarLocalStorage();
  
}

isSelected(coupon: Coupon) {
  return this.addCoupons.indexOf(coupon) != -1;
}

remove(i: number) {
   this.addCoupons.splice( i, 1);
   localStorage.setItem('cuponesArr',JSON.stringify(this.addCoupons));
  }

guardarLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('cuponesArr', JSON.stringify(this.addCoupons))
}

removerLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.removeItem('cuponesArr');
}

public applyCupon() {
  this.isValidatingCupon = true;
  const cupons = this.discountCodeTags.map(tag => tag.code);
  const currentCupon = this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value;
  if (!cupons.includes(currentCupon)) {
    const params = {
      coupon: this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value
    } as IDiscountCodeRequestParams;
    this.discountCodeImplement.validateDiscountCode$(params)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(response => {
        if (response.valid) {
            const couponInput = new Coupon ();
            couponInput.barCode = this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value;
            couponInput.productName = this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.value;
            this.addCoupons.push(couponInput);
            this.guardarLocalStorage();
            this.discountCodeForm.resetForm;
        } else {
          this.errorScheduleModalService.showErrorCouponModa(currentCupon);
        }
        this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.setValue('');
        this.isValidatingCupon = false;
      });
  } else {
    this.discountCodeForm.codeControl.setValue('');
  }

}

public removeDiscountCode($event: IDiscountCodeTag) {
  this.discountCodeTags = this.discountCodeTags.filter(code => code.code !== $event.code);
  this.couponsStore.removeCoupon($event.code);
  const cartRequest = this.shoppingCartRequest.shoppingCartRequest;
  cartRequest.discountsList = this.discountCodeTags.map(tag => {
    return {
      couponCode: tag.code,
      couponId: null,
      discountByReferenceId: null,
    } as IDiscountCode;
  });
  this.shoppingCartRequest.updateShoppingCartRequest = cartRequest;
  this.loadProductSummary();
}

handleError(error:HttpErrorResponse) {
  return throwError(error.message || 'Server Error')
}

private loadProductSummary() {
  this.shoppingCartImplement.getShoppingCart().pipe(
   
    take(1),
    catchError(catchError(this.handleError)))
    .subscribe((shoppingCartResponse: ShoppingCartResponse) => {
      console.log(shoppingCartResponse, 'Response Shopping');
    this.purchaseSummaryStore.setShoppingCartResponse(shoppingCartResponse);
    this.registerEventCheckout(shoppingCartResponse.shoppingList);

    const codeResponseDiscountedAmountCanonical = shoppingCartResponse.precalculation.discountedAmountCanonical.code;
    this.responseCard = {
      code:codeResponseDiscountedAmountCanonical,
      cuponesRedimidos: shoppingCartResponse.precalculation.discountedAmountCanonical.redeemedCoupon,
    };

    const cartRequest = this.shoppingCartRequest.shoppingCartRequest;
    const discountArray = isArray(cartRequest.discountsList) ? '' : '';

    this.dialogRef.close({
      data: this.responseCard,
      discountArray
      
    });

    
        
  }, (error) => {
      console.log(error, 'error cart')
      this.dialogRef.close(error);
  });
  
}


private registerEventCheckout(shoppingList: Array<ProductShoppingCart>) {
  if (!this.isShootTag) {
    const productSummaryList = isArray(shoppingList) ? shoppingList : [];
    TaggingService.checkout(productSummaryList);
    this.isShootTag = true;
  }
}
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="listado">
  <button mat-button class="close" (click)="closeDialog()"></button>
  <h2 mat-dialog-title>Cupones y Código de Descuento</h2>
  <div class="base_labels">
    <div
      class="labels_add"
      *ngFor="let coupon of addCoupons; let i = index"
      (click)="remove(i)"
    >
      <span class="label">
        {{ coupon.productName }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <hr />

  <div class="coupon_especiales">
    <p>
      Tienes {{coupons.length}} cupones especiales por ser parte del
      <span>monedero del ahorro,</span>
    </p>
    <p>¡elige los que prefieras y ahorra más!</p>
  </div>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="loader" *ngIf="loading"></div>
    <div *ngIf="coupons.length > 0">
      <div *ngFor="let coupon of coupons; let i = index">
        <div class="dialog-content">
          <div
            class="img-product"
            [ngClass]="{ 'img-product-disabled': isSelected(coupon) }"
          >
            <img [src]="coupon.pathImage.small" [alt]="coupon.productName" />
          </div>
          <div class="description_product">
            <div class="title_product">{{ coupon.productName }}</div>
            <p class="texto_product">
              Válido del
              {{ coupon.couponValidity.startDate | momentPipe: "D MMMM" }} al
              {{ coupon.couponValidity.endDate | momentPipe: "D MMMM YYYY" }}.
              <span class="detail_product_mobile"
                ><button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialogDetail(coupon)">
                  Ver más detalles
                </button></span
              >
            </p>
            <div class="detail_product_desktop">
              <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialogDetail(coupon)">
                Ver más detalles
              </button>
            </div>
            <div
              class="add_button_mobile"
              [ngClass]="{ disabled: isSelected(coupon) }"
            >
              <button (click)="agregar(coupon)"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="add_button_desktop"
            [ngClass]="{ disabled: isSelected(coupon) }"
          >
            <button (click)="agregar(coupon)"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <div class="codigo_descuento checkout-order-summary-component">
    <div class="titulo_codigo_descuento">¿Tienes un código de descuento?</div>
    <form
      [formGroup]="discountCodeForm.form"
      (ngSubmit)="applyCupon()"
      [hidden]="discountCodeTags.length > 0"
      class="block_codigo_descuento"
    >
      <div class="input_codigo_descuento">
        <fp-input-control
          [inputTitle]="''"
          [errorMessage]="''"
          [marginBottomZero]="true"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            id="nameCupon"
            class="input"
            placeholder="Ingresa un código"
            formControlName="code"
            [class.isinvalid]="!discountCodeForm.form.valid && discountCodeForm.form.touched"
          />
          <small class="small" *ngIf="!discountCodeForm.form.valid && discountCodeForm.form.touched">
            Código Inválido
          </small>
        </fp-input-control>
      </div>
      <div class="btn_agregar_codigo">
        <button
          type="submit"
          id="applyCoupon"
          class="btn btn-primary btn-aplicar"
          [disabled]="!discountCodeForm.form.valid || isValidatingCupon"
        >
          Agregar
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<mat-dialog-content *ngIf="detalle">
  <div class="top-detalle">
    <button mat-raised-button class="back" (click)="back()"></button>
    <h2>Detalle de cupón</h2>
  </div>
  <hr />

  <div class="cargando" *ngIf="!coupon; else loading">
    Cargando, Espere Por favor...
  </div>
  <ng-template #loading>
    <div class="cuerpo-detalle">
      <div class="descto">{{ coupon.productName }}</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Válido del
          {{ coupon.couponValidity.startDate | momentPipe: "D MMMM" }} al
          {{ coupon.couponValidity.endDate | momentPipe: "D MMMM YYYY" }}.
        </li>
        <li>Válido en nuestros locales, Web y App</li>
        <li>Para canjear en la botica, muestra el código.</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="terminos-condiciones">
        <div class="title_terminos_condiciones">Términos y condiciones</div>
        <p>
          {{ coupon.termsAndConditions }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa _"cuando se sale de la lista"_? ¿Estás cargando los valores desde el localStorage en `addCoupons`  al inicializar el componente o estás inicializando el arreglo vacío?

Comment: es una modal que carga un listado, allí se hace el agregado, cuando cierras el modal y lo vulvas abrir para añadir mas elementos agrega pero borra los ya añadidos en localatorage y necesito que los sume que no los borre

Comment: ese código es mas o menos lo que tengo...

Comment: Jaime Mendez, me podrías ayudar, puedo darte mas información, si es necesario.

Comment: Sixto pensé que ya habías resuelto el problema porque agregaste una respuesta. Si querías agregar más detalles lo correcto era editar la pregunta, no agregar una respuesta. En cuanto a tu código, no sé por qué tienes dos veces declarada `addCoupons` y está un poco extraño el código que adjuntas con ese forEach suelto ahí, pero definitivamente debes inicializar `addCoupons` a `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr'));` no a un arreglo vacío `[]`.

Comment: es un poco díficil explicar, puedo ponerte todo el código pero hay código adicional que no tiene nada que ver, trate de poner lo que podría servir, voy a editar mi respuesta y poner todo el código en la pregunta

Comment: Me pregunto cómo typescript no te da error por definir dos veces `addCoupons: Coupon[]`.

Comment: te puse todo el codigo el .ts, y el HTML

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136264/discussion-between-jaime-menendez-and-sixto-mujica).